# console.log from node.js application not splitting in multiple logs in sumoLogic

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, console.log, sumologic

I am using node.js for an internal application.
docker image of this node.js application is deployed.
Once deployed I see all the `console.log`s in `SumoLogic` but all the logs come as one big message. This makes it really difficult to debug in production. Is there a way to break my logs into separate messages in `SumoLogic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs for "Multiline Processing"](https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Collecting-Multiline-Logs).
Basically you can configure how should Sumo Logic split large messages into multiple ones. Check if you have this turned on:

- "Infer boundaries":

> This option will apply a set of default expressions, which are used to detect the beginning of a new multi-line message. When a message line matches one of these expressions, Sumo Logic waits until the next instance of this same expression, and then groups all lines between them as a single message.

And also "Boundary Regex" where you can specify a regular expression on what to be treated as a boundary between two log messages. Note that it's not always a line break as in some of the languages/frameworks you often get some structured data as one "piece of log". To be honest, I am not sure what is the nodejs standard here.

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.